# Spring Boot App on Azure with Command Line Arguments

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-webjobs

Is it possible to pass command line arguments to a Spring boot app on Azure via the web.config file?  Our app is up and running but we need to set the:

```
--spring.profiles.active=local
```

at startup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="ack=t-Djava.net.preferIPv4Strue -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\myjar-0.0.1.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 5):

I got a response from Microsoft and they had two ways:

1. Add "environmentVariables" block to the xml above:

Add "environmentVariables" block to the xml above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <handlers> 
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" /> 
    </handlers> 
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" 
    arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\AssetCommander-0.0.1.jar&quot;"> 
       <environmentVariables> 
          <environmentVariable name="JAVA_OPTS" value="-Dspring.profiles.active=dev" /> 
       </environmentVariables> 
    </httpPlatform> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

2. Add this in the App settings.

[[image]

3,  Actually, neither of those worked for us.  We had to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
            arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dspring.profiles.active=%spring.profiles.active% -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\AssetCommander-0.0.1.jar&quot;">
            </httpPlatform>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

AND #2 above.

Comment: We were facing the same issue, I ended up trying #2 by itself and that worked. Are you sure you hit Save when you added the key-value pair to the application settings?

Comment: Our devops team did number 2 only. It works like a charm. +1

Answer (score 2):

Configuration-> Application Settings,
I've simply added:

[image]

After that, Springboot could load: application-prod.properties

Comment: I have just spend hours trying to figure this out, and this was the answer I was looking for! I was trying to deploy the sample pet clinic application [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic) and have it use the postgres profile which reference environment variables that I had set to point to an Azure Database for PostgreSQL. Thank you again!